# How to apply for Verification for calendar-api call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

How do I get my small app verified so that USERS can utilize the product and not be told it is unsafe?

[image]

Email from google:

> Verification Status Verification in progress The Trust and Safety team has received your form. They will reach out to you via your contact email if needed. The review process can take up to 4-6 weeks. Expect the first email from our Trust and Safety team within 3-5 days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use.

I have been waiting over 4 months now

Comment: Verification Status
 Verification in progress
The Trust and Safety team has received your form. They will reach out to you via your contact email if needed. The review process can take up to 4-6 weeks. Expect the first email from our Trust and Safety team within 3-5 days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use.

Comment: been waiting over 4 months now...

Comment: Hi ! What are you exactly trying to achieve? Are you trying to publish a web app? An app that uses Google Calendar API? An Add-On? Could you please describe further what you are trying to publish and how far in the process have you reached (it is all develop and just needs verification, it is on the testing stage, etc)? Thanks ! :D

Comment: @Luke you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  I have edited your question in an attempted to improve it.  You should include all information in the question itself rather than as comments.

Comment: I am trying to display a persons calendar on a WEB APPLICATION.   if they are free or busy.  Then an end user may create an event on that calendar if they want.  I am trying to test it, but the end users  do not understand the UNSAFE BUTTON && I submitted for verification a long time ago and still nothing has happened.

Answer (score 2):

## Back ground info

An unverified app is an app or Apps Script that requests a sensitive or restricted OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process. Users of unverified apps or your test builds might get warnings based on the OAuth scopes you're using. This is to protect users and their data from deceptive apps.

- Unverified app screen:  -The app or script might display an "unverified app" screen before it displays the consent screen.
- Security Check: Security Checkup might show your app as risky and unverified.
- Unverified app user cap: To protect users and Google systems from abuse, apps that use OAuth and Cloud Identity have certain quota restrictions based on the risk level of the OAuth scopes an app uses.

Go to google developer console for your project and submit it for verification.  Under OAuth consent screen you will find information on how to proceed.

[image]

[Docs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)

## Takes time

The verification process takes time months in fact.  I recommend that you check your spam mail to ensure that you have not missed an email from google. Other wise you should just wait to hear from them.  You could try to change your scopes and submit the request again.

Comment: THIS WAS DONE OVER 6 MONTHS AGO,  STILL WAITING && CLIENTS would like to test & use it,  but still waiting for verification

Comment: I'm sorry for your frustrated but yelling at me is not going to get you verified any faster.   I suggest you resubmit it.   You probably missed an email from Google in your spam folder.   Asking for a create event scope on Google Calendar is always going to trigger a review.

Comment: Hi ! If you have a Google Workspace account you can also contact the support team, please follow [these instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) to do so.

Comment: MATEO  !!   THANKS

Comment: MATEO, thank you for knowing how to reach them!   Hopefully it will help get it resolved.

Comment: Luke@ - were you able to verify your app ? Is this resolved ?